# Unable to install Ubuntu 12.04 lts 64 bit

Tags: installation

I am unable to install 12.04 LTS 64 bit on my 64 bit m/c having Windows 8.

I have a partition of 95 GB NTFS where I want to install it.

I tried the windows installer, but when asked for reboot, it cannot reboot. Only a beep comes with black screen.

I tried the USB installer, but in vain. Here I get the home screen to choose options but when I choose either to run or install it, a beep is all that is made and nothing happens.

Please help me install Ubuntu.

Comment: System specification please?

Answer (score -2):

please, try to format that partition as FAT32 or Ext4, then try to install. NTFS formated disk is compatibile with windows, and in most cases with windows only. so you need or FAT32 or Ext4 formated that partition for linux.

Comment: With the Windows installer (Wine), Ubuntu is installed on a squashfs disk image residing on an NTFS partition. So NTFS works fine for this. An ext4 partition will *not* work for this; Wubi is a Windows-based solution that doesn't repartition or rely on partition changes to install and work. In other situations (besides Wubi), where Ubuntu has its own separate partitions, neither NTFS nor FAT32 will work. Ubuntu must at minimum have a partition for the `/` filesystem; this must support Unix-style permissions (no NTFS, but also no FAT32). Also, *Ubuntu can almost always make its own partitions.*

Comment: in the question is not stated that it is wubi installer, NTFS will not work with linux, BUT FAT32 WILL. go to sleap please...

Comment: Please read my comment more carefully. It explains, in detail, why FAT32 will not work for a Wubi system. Or if you prefer, the short version: *The whole point of Wubi is to have an Ubuntu system without having to have any partitions besides NTFS.* (My comment above also, separately, explains why it will not work for any other kind of Ubuntu system either. Which is relevant because the OP here *also tried the USB installer*; that is, also tried to install a regular, non-Wubi system.)

Comment: my comment also explains that i told for linux official installation, as in question is not stated that is wubi installation, so read my comment above more carrefully...

Comment: Like I said, FAT32 is wrong *for all Ubuntu installations, not just Wubi.*

Comment: "A popular format compatible with almost any device or system, tipically used for file exchange." simple definition of fat formated disks...

Comment: FAT32 can be *read* and *written* by almost any device or operating system. It cannot be *installed on* by most operating systems. Actually, *Windows* no longer supports installing on FAT32!

Comment: of course, Ext4 is better for linux, but you can install it on FAT32 and you can make partition to 32gb big that is not limited in Ext4, but limitation not means that could not be used for linux...

Comment: You *cannot* install it on FAT32. This has nothing to do with size limitations. As I explained in my first comment, FAT32 does not support Unix-style permissions, which are required for the `/` partition of an Ubuntu system.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive

Comment: and than, special accent on sentence, that is written just for you here: " If you are new to file systems and partitioning, please do some preliminary research on the two before you attempt this procedure."

Comment: That page *explicitly states* that it is recommending FAT32 specifically for sharing files between systems. The entire focus of that article is adding an *additional storage drive* to an *already existing* Ubuntu system. FAT32 is *not* being recommended for *installing* Ubuntu. Please consider that none of your sources have supported anything you have said so far. It turns out that I actually have researched this, and that I *apply* my knowledge about partition types and Linux on a regular basis.

Comment: Although your recommendation that the OP should format the 95 GB partition as FAT32 is wrong, and *Ubuntu* does not support installing to FAT32, and FAT32 is the *wrong* filesystem to install any Linux distro, it occurs to me that *maybe your answer can be improved.* While there is absolutely no reason for the OP here to do this (so you might not want to expend the time and energy), you might argue that it is *theoretically* possible to get an Ubuntu system running from a FAT32 partition with the *umsdos* driver. This is the only thing I can think of that might support what you've been saying.